# adding a visible scrollbar to a widget

Tags: android

I have the following code to get the entered text scolling. It scrolls but I am not able to see the scrollbar. I want to see the scrollbar visible every time irrespective of the data available

```
text.setSingleLine(false);
text.setScroller(new Scroller(this));
text.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
text.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
text.setMaxLines(3);
text.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code in your layout file. This will allow you to visible scroll bars every time.

```
android:fadeScrollbars="false"
```

Or you can also use following code to do so

```
scrollView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```

### Exapme

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false">
```

**Reference**

- [ScrollView:fadeScrollbars](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:fadeScrollbars)
- [setScrollbarFadingEnabled(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScrollbarFadingEnabled%28boolean%29)

Comment: But I want to add them on the fly without using xml file.They work but they are not visible.

Comment: have you tried `scrollView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);` method?

Answer (score 0):

You must set the position, style, size and fade to guarantee it to be visible. Example:

```
text.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
text.setScrollBarSize(5);
text.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: I added those line but getting Nullpointer exception on onDrawScrollBar and something related to ViewGroup draw

Comment: Show the code where you get the NullPointer, please.